# Why is the chemical of an hexose not sufficient to ID the molecule?

Tags: biochemistry, homework, carbohydrates

Here is the homework question I have to answer to

> The Chemical formula C6H12O6 can mean any number of different hexose sugars that share the same chemical formula. To tell the hexoses apart, you would need to see their structural formula. This is because they are ___________ of each other

My thoughts are ...

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Your question is off-topic because 1) It is more of a chemistry question than a biology question and 2) homework questions are off-topic unless you've shown your attempt at solving it.

Comment: The format of your question is not great. Just to show you what a good format is, I edited your post. Of course, as it is a homework question, I can't fill up for you what your thoughts on the question is. Good luck

Comment: @Justin The question is saying that, based on the specific notation being used to represent this molecule, i.e., by expressing the molecule using its chemical formula, it's not possible to distinguish different hexose sugars (sugars with six carbons) from each other simply by considering their chemical formula. Instead, you would need to use structural formula notation. The reason why you need to do this is because different molecules that have the same chemical formula, but different structural configurations, are considered to be _______ of each other.